# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

When i need to migrate bootstrap from 0.14 to 2.5, i got this error.
When i put angular-ui-bootstrap 0.14 it works but not when i change js of 2.5.
I'm new and need a help. Thanks

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.9%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3DdatepickerDirectiveProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2F127.255.0.0%3A444%2FScripts%2FUntyped%2FLibs%2Fangular.min.js%...Libs%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A382)][1](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.9%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3DdatepickerDirectiveProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2F127.255.0.0%3A444%2FScripts%2FUntyped%2FLibs%2Fangular.min.js%25...Libs%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A382))
>       at angular.min.js:6
>       at angular.min.js:40
>       at q (angular.min.js:7)
>       at g (angular.min.js:39)
>       at eb (angular.min.js:43)
>       at c (angular.min.js:21)
>       at Object.Ic [as bootstrap] (angular.min.js:21)
>       at Object.bootstrap (app.js?v=800b39c1-3165-4fc0-a44d-1a6c904b6e18:46)
>       at app.js?v=800b39c1-3165-4fc0-a44d-1a6c904b6e18:46
>       at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:42)

In my app.ts:

```
var app: angular.IModule =
        angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies',
            'angular-loading-bar',
            'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ngSignalR',
            'angularMoment', 'ngTranslate', 'ui.bootstrap',
            'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker', 'ngToast',
            'tmh.dynamicLocale', 'googlechart', 'ng.deviceDetector', 'nzToggle',
            'ui.select', 'ui.router', 'unsavedChanges', 'ngAutocomplete',
            "xeditable", "ui.calendar", "infinite-scroll", 'LocalStorageModule', 'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.config(['$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        ($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => { return new Config($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider); }]);

 app.controller('SignupCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$state', '$sce', '$anchorScroll', '$uibModal', 'ModalService', 'UsersService', 'ConfigService',
        Application.Controllers.Signup]);
```

Comment: @Mickers yeah i mean myApp in the exception

Comment: What do you mean when you say " i change js of 2.5"? Include the `<script>` elements in the question. It’s really hard to answer a question about a bug in code when the question *doesn’t include the buggy code.*

Comment: please add full error msg and html as well.